# How to make flock block if other process locked the file?

Tags: php, flock

I have a JavaScript application which posts messages to server. I have to gather those messages on server side and analyse them later, so I'm simply writing them to file. The problem is, when I open the file for reading, ie. in Notepad, messages are not being written. Since flock() is blocking and the locks should be mandatory on Windows, I expected the script to simply wait until I close the file and then save all pending messages, but it doesn't seem to work this way. Is there a way to make sure that all messages will finally be saved to the file, even if other process got exclusive access to it? I can't lose any message, even if someone opens the file for reading or copies it. Can I achieve it with PHP, or maybe I should rather send messages to database instead? PHP version is 7.0.4, my script looks like this:

```
$f = fopen('log.csv', 'a+');
flock($f, LOCK_EX);

$text = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). ";" .htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]). PHP_EOL;
clearstatcache();

fwrite($f, $text);
fflush($f);

flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

flock returns true if successful or false if failed.

```
while(!flock($f, LOCK_EX)) {
  sleep(5);
}
```

This won't fix the problem of your script timing out if another process has it locked for a long time. In that case, you might want to close the file and try opening a different file name.

Comment: I would rather have it all in one place. And it won't help if other process locks the second file...